# SIP Application on standalone Red5 Server does not connect to Asterisk Server

Tags: red5, sip, asterisk, rtmp

I have tried for days now trying to find the right version of red5phone, but to no avail. Also, I need red5 and asterisk to be on different servers. I have followed all instructions described in the various tutorials on web, but nothing helps. I have downloaded 2 different versions of red5phone: `sip1`, `sip_47` from the red5phone google code site, but none of them worked!

When I use:
a) sip1 - shows the correct parameters being passed on the red5 server console, but connection is stuck up with the console displaying the following error:

```
[NioProcessor-1] ERROR o.r.server.service.ServiceInvoker - Method login with parameters [<sip user>, <sip user>,<sip user>,<sip user pwd>, <asterisk server i/p>, <asterisk server i/p>] not found in org.red5.server.webapp.sip.Application@2d0c94a7
```

b) sip47 - when I type in the values in the flex interface and check the red5 server console, I see all parameters correct(the ones I passed) except for asterisk server ip that i m trying to connect. Instead, it shows 127.0.0.1 by default and completely ignores the passed ip and regsitration fails.

I am using:

```
red5 server version: 0.9.1, centos: 4.8(final), red5phone used: sip_47 (tried sip1 as well)
```

As a desperate measure I tried debugging the source code for red5phone (java and flex files) myself. but when I try to create the environment on my local system, I get several compile errors for missing java packages such as javax.media, org.slf4j, org.red5, etc. really confused and desperate for some guidance. Any tips highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sunil, I'm also new to this, I would try `red5-voicebridge` installed in your `red5` server.

[red5-voicebridge](http://code.google.com/p/red5-voicebridge)  Please let me know if you got it to work.